# Performance gaps between computers

Tags: windows, performance, benchmarking

The same program is running on two different computers.
The program writes some data to a file from time to time.
The first - i5-1.7 Ghz, 4G Ram
The second - i5-1.9 Ghz, 4G ram, full ssd HD.

The expected result will be that the second computer will run the program faster than the first.
The actual result is that the program runs much slower (60% deficit) on the second computer.

Is it possible? Am I missing some environmental variable?

Comment: Can you provide us with performance view from task manager while running your benchmark? perhaps you have other processes running that make this gap

Comment: Good point.. The first computer has utilisation of 5% average cpu at rest and 80% memory. The second has 3% cpu and 67% memory. When working the first has 17% average, and second 30% average. Still odd to me :/

Comment: *"The program writes some data to a file from time to time* - what does it do the rest of the time? Also, you didn't even specify which CPUs you are using (i5 has 6 different generations in the market, each with a steady growth in performance over the previous one)

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple description of the two computer hardware, I can not see what from the data you provide. Compare two computers with a detailed configuration.

Comment: Ok.. Can you please tell me how to extract the information you think that will be relevant?

Comment: [link](http://www.ludashi.com)  I usually use this.I dont know if you read Chinese...